# Db modification in onFocusChanged

Tags: android, sqlite, event-handling

In the onFocusChanged event, when EditText lose focus, I update new data in sqlite.

It is working well, but if I give back button, the activity is destroyed but it doesn't enter in onFocusChange, so it does not update my db.

What should I do?

I tried with the TextWatcher Interface, but I need the id of the view to update the correct field in db.

Comment: why dont you implement the same code in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`? `onPause()` would be a better choice because the data will be saved anytime the activity is off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle), the correct place to save your data is in your activity's `onPause` callback.

The `onFocusChanged` callback is interesting only when you actually care which of multiple views currently has the focus, i.e., when the behaviour of these multiple views depends on the state of each other.